# How to Animate an Element Within a Parent in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, controltemplate

I have created a custom style/control template for the ToggleButton control that makes it look like a Toggle Switch.

Currently, I use a Trigger on IsChecked to set the HorizontalAlignment of the switch to Left or Right.

However, this is not a very good user experience.

When the control goes into the Checked visual state, I want the switch to animate/slide over to the right, and when it goes into the Unchecked visual state, I want the switch to animate/slide over to the left.

Here is a super-simple look at the XAML in the control template.

```
<Grid x:Name="RootElement">
    ...
    <Grid x:Name="SwitchElement">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

How do I go about creating the storyboard/animation for SwitchElement so that it translates over to fit within the width of the RootElement?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by check/unchecked visual state? Do you mean you have a checkbox that will show/hide the element or under what circumstances do you want the box to toggle positions?

Comment: In a ControlTemplate there is the VisualStateManager which uses VisualStateGroups to organize individual VisualState(s). For a ToggleButton control, there are two visual states for when the control is "Checked" or "Unchekced".

Comment: Edited to make my goal hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a Grid does fit your needs maybe you try something like a dockpanel and a Trigger to move the SwitchElement to Dock.Right

Something like this:

```
<ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border Width="50" Height="25" Background="Transparent">
                    <Canvas>
                        <Ellipse Name="SliderElement" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="0" Height="25" Width="25">
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard  >
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="25" Duration="0:0:0.4" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="SliderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: I already set the HorizonalAlignment property to Left or Right depending on the IsChecked property, but that is not a good user experience. It will be better if the SwitchElement animates/slides back and forth. That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @keithernet i refactored this to use a animation and move the ellipse in a canvas. you can also animate your translate Transform of your example. You just have to name it. And set the Storyboard.TargetName

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem was to build the animation in code and apply it as a behavior. The problem is that animations in XAML cannot be dynamic and use Bindings because they are frozen at runtime.

By creating my slide animation in code, I was able to use a binding that looked at the parent's ActualWidth.

I have now expanded this behavior into a full-fledged animation behavior that I can use in many other places.